# How to clip content from a scrollable main div underneath a floating navbar above?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, clip

I'm trying to find a portable solution to a layout design, wherein a navbar partially obscures the content inside of a main div beneath it. The content in the main div should clip beyond the main div's bounds so that the content may render beneath the navbar.

[image: Sample of desired behaviour]

In the sample above, the main div and the navbar div do not overlap. The scrollbar rests entirely within the bounds of the main div, while the content inside is obscured by the navbar (the blur effect is irrelevant, just a sample application.)

My current solution is to overlay the navbar above the main div, and set the main div `padding-top` equal to the height of the navbar like so:

[image]

The elements/styles are arranges something like this:

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="navbar"> ... </div>
  <div id="main"> ... </div>
</div>
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: NAVBAR_CLEARANCE;
  z-index: 1;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: NAVBAR_CLEARANCE;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

This works just fine for browsers that support `-webkit-scrollbar` selectors, since I can easily re-position the scrollbar to fit entirely within the main div (omitted for clairty.) However, for browsers like Firefox, the second image is exactly what the user sees.

Is there a portable solution for achieving the results as shown in image 1?

EDIT:
I created a JSFiddle for sample 2:

https://jsfiddle.net/rpacmovj/18/

Comment: sorry for the question, it's just to understand. You want scrollbar to go under nav as on image 2?

Comment: I prefer the scrollbar to remain inside main. Image 2 is my current solution, but I make adjustments to the scrollbar which I omit in this question for clarity.

Comment: I checked you jsfiddle, seems ok! You have the navbar with fixed position and a z-index. You have scroll on main. I think you should put overflow hidden on body to avoid double scrollbar. And you don't need the position absolute for the main except if it's for something else than the scroll

Answer (score 0):

**this is what you trying to do?**

```css
#navbar {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

#main {
  position: "absolute";
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: "NAVBAR_CLEARANCE";
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="navbar">top Header  </div>
  <div id="main"> sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb sjdhf  fjbjhjsd bfjh bdsfjhb dshj bfhjsdb .. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For styling the navbar, yes :) Actually, I use a :before element that contains some blur as a backdrop for the navbar.

Comment: if not get what you want then add your full code on www.codepen.io then give us that link then people will check and implement it.

Comment: you can stop overlapping with navbar.. let #main div scrollable only? and that main div won't overlap with navbar **it will scroll below navbar div that you want it**?